# hard integral inequality with $e^{x^2}$

Tags: integral-inequality

a) prove the convergency of 
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac {\cosh x \cdot \sin x} {x\cdot e^{x^2}}$$
b) prove the inequality
$$ \int_0^{\frac {7\pi} {12}} \dfrac {\cosh x \cdot \sin x} {x\cdot e^{x^2}}<1$$
c) prove the inequality
$$ \int_0^{\frac {2\pi} {3}} \dfrac {\cosh x \cdot \sin x} {x\cdot e^{x^2}}>1$$

I have used some Sandor aproximations for b)and c) and even some results of Zitian and Yebing but without success. Any kind of proof is welcome.Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that $b)$ is correct.

Comment: i did numerical for bond $\dfrac {\pi} 2$ but is not good for covering the area, the error is to big,wolframalpha gave  me the bond of $\dfrac {7\pi} {12}$ did you prove it or just calculated in mathematica

Comment: $b)$ is correct: it is $0.995311$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: yes it is, numerically the LHS of $b)$ is about $0.995311$.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\cosh(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi},$$
hence convergence follows from $\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\leq 1$.

Comment: yes Jack D'Aurizio,it also follows from nice inequality $\dfrac {\cosh x} {e^{x^2}} \le 1$

Comment: btw if someone can explain,how do i accept an answer,and how could i make dead posts alive again,e.g. here is nice solution http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294971/find-big-a-b-big-biga-big-bigb-big-ge-2-sqrt3-text-and-f

Comment: Analytical proofs of inequalities like these that are extremely precise (numerically $0.995 < 1$ and $1 <1.005$) are seldom very illuminating - just careful estimation and alot of work. Anyway we can for example do it with a $30$ order Taylor series of the full integrand, or we can do it with a $4$th order Taylor series of $\frac{\cosh(t)\sin(t)}{t}$ + knowledge of some values of the error-function (which can be found in normal distribution tables if you really want to avoid direct numerics).